# main.css file reference in index.html points to a main.scss file

Tags: css, sass

In my index.html file I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

When I look at styles/ path I see there a main.scss file.

Why does the above reference to the main.css work if there is only a .scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to convert the `.scss` to `.css`.

You can easily do it from http://sassmeister.com/

Paste in the contents of the `.scss` file and with the resulting CSS save it as `main.css`.

Answer (score 0):

the .scss file refers to [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). my guess is that the main.css file was never generated. if you've never worked with Sass before, you'll need to read up on setting up your environment for it.